# How can I disable clicks for a jRange slider?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, click

I'm using a jRange slider which takes a hidden HTML input and adds a custom slider , and customizing it so that, with three sliders, the total value won't exceed 100. I've managed to get everything working fine for click-and-drag however simply clicking on the slider itself allows the handle to move beyond the acceptable range. I've tried various ways to disable clicks, but none seem to have any effect. i.e.

```
#quant1 { pointer-events: none; }

$("#quant1").on("click mouseup mousedown", function(e){
e.preventDefault();
console.log("trying to intercept----");
return false;
});

$("#quant1").unbind("click");
```

My code is below

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="./jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./jquery.range.css">
<script src="./jquery.range.js"></script>
<script>


</script>
<style>
    #quant1 { pointer-events: none; }
</style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="foo1" style="height: 100px; width: 100%;" ></div>
<input type="hidden" id="quant1" value="0" />
<div id="foo1" style="height: 100px; width: 100%;" ></div>
<input type="hidden" id="quant2" value="0" />

<div id="foo2" style="height: 100px; width: 100%;" ></div>
<input type="hidden" id="quant3" value="0" />
<div id="foo3" style="height: 100px; width: 100%;" ></div>
<div id="totalRemaining">100 </div>


<script >
var maxVal=100;
$_slider1= $("#quant1");
$_slider1.find('.ui-slider-handle');
$_slider2= $("#quant2");




// With JQuery
$('#quant1').jRange(
{
    from: 0.0,
    to: 100.0,
    step: 1,
    scale: [0,25,50,75,100],
    format: '%s',
    width: 300,
    showLabels: true,
    snap: true,
    id: "thisisanid",
    slide:function(){console.log("sliding")},
    ondragend: function(){  console.log("ondragend");    
        var reduceSliderVal= reduceSlider($_slider1, $_slider2);// returns the appropriate slider value or returns false if no adjustement is needed.
        if (reduceSliderVal){$_slider1.jRange('setValue', ""+reduceSliderVal);}
    }
}).change(function(){
    console.log("change");
        var reduceSliderVal= reduceSlider($_slider1, $_slider2);// returns the appropriate slider value or returns false if no adjustement is needed.
        if (reduceSliderVal){ $_slider1.jRange('setValue', ""+reduceSliderVal);}
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            console.log("slider 1 timeout onchange");

            var reduceSliderVal= reduceSlider($_slider1, $_slider2);// returns the appropriate slider value or returns false if no adjustement is needed.
            if (reduceSliderVal){ $_slider1.jRange('setValue', ""+reduceSliderVal);}

        }, 3000);
         //reduces the current slider val if needed
         $_slider1.trigger("ondragend");
            console.log("onchange slider1", reduceSliderVal); 
            console.log("after");
}).on('input mousedown mouseup touchstart click change ondrag', function (e) {
    console.log("triggering dragend slider1");
    $_slider1.trigger("ondragend");

});

$('#quant2').jRange({
    from: 0,
    to: 100,
    step: 1,
    scale: [0,25,50,75,100],
    format: '%s',
    width: 300,
    showLabels: true,
    ondragend: function(){      
        var reduceSliderVal= reduceSlider($_slider2, $_slider1);// returns the appropriate slider value or returns false if no adjustement is needed.
        if (reduceSliderVal){$_slider2.jRange('setValue', ""+reduceSliderVal);}
    }
}).change(function(){
        var reduceSliderVal= reduceSlider($_slider2, $_slider1);// returns the appropriate slider value or returns false if no adjustement is needed.
        if (reduceSliderVal){ $_slider2.jRange('setValue', ""+reduceSliderVal);} //reduces the current slider val if needed
});

function reduceSlider(currentSlider, otherSlider, otherSlider2)
{ // if the slider value of the just-moved slider is too high, reduce it to the appropriate amount
     var negativeExcess= maxVal -  ( parseInt(currentSlider.val() ) + parseInt(otherSlider.val() ) );

    if (negativeExcess < 0)
    {
         console.log("excess calculated", negativeExcess);
         console.log("returning ", (maxVal - parseInt( otherSlider.val() )  )  );
        return (maxVal - parseInt(otherSlider.val())  ); //calculate remainder without involving the current slider since the user may drag the current slider too far beyond the max value, resulting in the current slider being set backwards too far. 
    }else{
            return false;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

​The jRange plugin provides the function `onbarclicked` to listen for when the slider is clicked. Unfortunately, this is called after the update to the slider has already occurred, making it not very useful for your purposes.

Taking a look at the jRange source, it would be ideal if we could override the `barClicked` function of the plugin. However, unfortunately this function has been made private through the use of a closure.

That leaves you with the less desirable option of directly editing the plugin itself. I've included an example of this below, where the `barClicked` function now just returns `false`, thereby disabling the user's ability to adjust the range bars by clicking instead of dragging.

```html
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://s3.amazonaws.com/so-answers/jquery.range.css">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/so-answers/jquery.range-modified.js"></script>
<script>


</script>
<style>
    #quant1 { pointer-events: none; }
</style>


</head>
<body>
<div id="foo1" style="height: 100px; width: 100%;" ></div>
<input type="hidden" id="quant1" value="0" />
<div id="foo1" style="height: 100px; width: 100%;" ></div>
<input type="hidden" id="quant2" value="0" />

<div id="foo2" style="height: 100px; width: 100%;" ></div>
<input type="hidden" id="quant3" value="0" />
<div id="foo3" style="height: 100px; width: 100%;" ></div>
<div id="totalRemaining">100 </div>


<script >
var maxVal=100;
$_slider1= $("#quant1");
$_slider1.find('.ui-slider-handle');
$_slider2= $("#quant2");




// With JQuery
$('#quant1').jRange(
{
    from: 0.0,
    to: 100.0,
    step: 1,
    scale: [0,25,50,75,100],
    format: '%s',
    width: 300,
    showLabels: true,
    snap: true,
    id: "thisisanid",
    slide:function(){console.log("sliding")},
    ondragend: function(){  console.log("ondragend");    
        var reduceSliderVal= reduceSlider($_slider1, $_slider2);// returns the appropriate slider value or returns false if no adjustement is needed.
        if (reduceSliderVal){$_slider1.jRange('setValue', ""+reduceSliderVal);}
    }
}).change(function(){
    console.log("change");
        var reduceSliderVal= reduceSlider($_slider1, $_slider2);// returns the appropriate slider value or returns false if no adjustement is needed.
        if (reduceSliderVal){ $_slider1.jRange('setValue', ""+reduceSliderVal);}
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            console.log("slider 1 timeout onchange");

            var reduceSliderVal= reduceSlider($_slider1, $_slider2);// returns the appropriate slider value or returns false if no adjustement is needed.
            if (reduceSliderVal){ $_slider1.jRange('setValue', ""+reduceSliderVal);}

        }, 3000);
         //reduces the current slider val if needed
         $_slider1.trigger("ondragend");
            console.log("onchange slider1", reduceSliderVal); 
            console.log("after");
}).on('input mousedown mouseup touchstart click change ondrag', function (e) {
    console.log("triggering dragend slider1");
    $_slider1.trigger("ondragend");

});

$('#quant2').jRange({
    from: 0,
    to: 100,
    step: 1,
    scale: [0,25,50,75,100],
    format: '%s',
    width: 300,
    showLabels: true,
    ondragend: function(){      
        var reduceSliderVal= reduceSlider($_slider2, $_slider1);// returns the appropriate slider value or returns false if no adjustement is needed.
        if (reduceSliderVal){$_slider2.jRange('setValue', ""+reduceSliderVal);}
    }
}).change(function(){
        var reduceSliderVal= reduceSlider($_slider2, $_slider1);// returns the appropriate slider value or returns false if no adjustement is needed.
        if (reduceSliderVal){ $_slider2.jRange('setValue', ""+reduceSliderVal);} //reduces the current slider val if needed
});

function reduceSlider(currentSlider, otherSlider, otherSlider2)
{ // if the slider value of the just-moved slider is too high, reduce it to the appropriate amount
     var negativeExcess= maxVal -  ( parseInt(currentSlider.val() ) + parseInt(otherSlider.val() ) );

    if (negativeExcess < 0)
    {
         console.log("excess calculated", negativeExcess);
         console.log("returning ", (maxVal - parseInt( otherSlider.val() )  )  );
        return (maxVal - parseInt(otherSlider.val())  ); //calculate remainder without involving the current slider since the user may drag the current slider too far beyond the max value, resulting in the current slider being set backwards too far. 
    }else{
            return false;
    }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```